# Can telemedicine be used in migraine care?

Tags: headache, migraine

How safe and reliable is a diagnosis of migraines through telemedicine (remote diagnosis)?

E.g. A patient and doctor go on video call, patient describes and attempts to demonstrates symptoms, and then doctor creates diagnosis.

Comment: Can you expound on this please?

Comment: This question has 4 close votes for being unclear. David Liu's edits clarify the question, but it still lacks prior research. I'm putting it on hold until it meets site guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent study published in [Cephalalgia](https://doi.org/10.1177/0333102419868250) proved telemedicine is feasible in migraine care. 
Fifty patients were studied, clinical outcomes were as good in telemedicine as in the in-office group. Convenience was rated higher and visit times were shorter in the telemedicine group.